# Send data from nodejs to angularjs

Tags: angularjs, node.js

In WebStorm, can I run Angular and Node in the same project? Is there a project template for this?

i want to send an array from nodejs route to angularjs

Thank you!

this is my code

conroller.js

```
         $http({
       method: 'GET',
      url: '/Profil'
      }).then(function (success){
       console.log("i get the data");
       $scope.items=success;
       },function (error){

         });
```

Nodejs file :

```
      personne1={FirstName:"a", contry:"usa",LastName:"sfn"};
     personne2={FirstName:"b", contry:"usa",LastName:"sfn"};
       personne3={FirstName:"x", contry:"usa",LastName:"sfn"};
      list=[personne1,personne2,personne3];

        console.log("hello from profil");

    res.render('Profil',{items:list});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Angular](https://angularjs.org/) is a frontend JavaScript library. [NodeJS](https://nodejs.org/en/) is a runtime environment using [Chrome's V8 engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chrome_V8) for your backend. Using them together is quite possible. One such example is a [MEAN stack](http://mean.io/) (MongoDB, Express, Angular, Node).

To get started in Webstorm, Jetbrains [has a help page](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/angular.html). There is also a [starter](https://github.com/scotch-io/starter-node-angular) that you can grab from Github.

Happy coding!

Comment: Yes this is exaclty what i'm using but i'm tryingto send data from nodejs to angulars but it's doesnt' work form me this is my code

Comment: Please post all of your code in the question for a deeper review